# How to get updated ID from array when calling set state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app:
In a child component I am calling setState and I am adding a user to a list of users within a javascript array. I would like to get the index or id of that user returned to the child component.

What would the best approach be to use the setState callback function to return the ID to the child component?

Current attempt:

Event used in child component to add new user in parent component:

```
// would like user ID that was added into state to be returned
this.props.updateScope("createNewUser", userDetails)
```

Button used in child component to create a new user

```
         <Button
            onClick={this.newUserHandler}
            role="button"
            variant="outline-dark"
            block
          >
            New User
          </Button>
```

In parent component: (this is not working as method finishes before returning)

```
  case "createNewUser":
    let userDetails = {
      name: "",
      description: "",
      stories: []
    };

    if (scopeInformation.hasOwnProperty("name")) {
      userDetails.name = scopeInformation.name;
    }

    if (scopeInformation.hasOwnProperty("description")) {
      userDetails.description = scopeInformation.description;
    }

    // todo: confirm user details working here
    const updatedUsers = [
      ...this.state.projectInformation.scope.users,
      userDetails
    ];

    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        updatedUsers: updatedUsers 
      },
      () => {
        return updatedUsers.length;
      }
    );
```

The parent component contains an array of users, within the child component there is a button I am using

Comment: add some code which you have tried

Comment: add your code please

Comment: I have added some code now

Comment: Can you give a bit more context on what you're trying to do here? (Like why you want to pass the IDs, what is the role of the parent vs child components, etc) There might be many ways to do what you want.

Comment: In react world you never "return", you just the update state of the component. It would be great if you share a complete component code.

What is `lastUsersID`?

Comment: You mention `index`, is this "child" being rendered as part of an array::map in the parent component? Please share [Minimal and Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code that accurately reproduces your issue. Please include specific details of your attempt and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen how would I get the ID of that user that I just added then?

Comment: @HenryWoody I would like to get the ID of the user that was added so I could select that user in the child component which renders the list of users

Comment: Hi @DrewReese I have made some changes now

Comment: Have you tried passing the new ID back to the child component via prop(s)? *Some* ancestor presumably has the source of truth array of users (with IDs). Another option I can think of is to pass a callback from the child back to the parent in the parent's callback, but that is already not a great idea as it's messy and data in react already naturally flows in the direction of parent to child.

Answer (score 0):

You can have separate state for the last user id and set this state whenever you get the new user, something like following:

```
state = {
  lastAddedUserId: "",
  .....
}

const updatedUsers = [
  ...this.state.projectInformation.scope.users,
  userDetails
];
this.setState({lastAddedUserId: userDetails.id});
```

OR

As you told that users data is being stored in array and you are using spread operator to add the newly entered user so you can always pick the last index of the array something like:

```
const updatedUsers = [
  ...this.state.projectInformation.scope.users,
  userDetails
];
const lastAddedUserId = updatedUsers[updatedUsers.length - 1].id;
```